# How to append json array to value attribute

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

There is a search box in my view.

[image: img]

When i search product on here it will retrieve(single) product using ajax

my ajax code is

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#update_prod").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var head = $("#update_product").val();
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      type: "post",
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/update_product",
      data: {
        product: head
      },
      success: function(data) {

      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

so in Controller

```
public function update_product() {
  $product = $_POST['product'];
  $query = $this - > db - > query("Select  * From product Where  title Like '%$product%' and online=1");
  $result = $query - > result_array();
  echo json_encode($result);
}
```

and im reviving data in my console

```
[{
  "id": "99",
  "brand_id": "8",
  "category_id": "1",
  "mark": "0",
  "title": "Corsair Memory - 1GB 533MHz DDR2 Desktop Memory(VS1GB533D2 ",
  " model ": " Corsair Memory - 1 GB ",
  " sub ": " Corsair Memory - 1 GB DDR2 Desktop Memory ",
  "price": "3250",
  "price_update": "1",
  "description": "",
  "overview": "1",
  "offer": "0",
  "stock": "0",
  "online": "1",
  "other": "0",
  "video": "0",
  "valid": "Price Valid 2 Weeks Only"
}]
```

> My **Question is** how to retrieve data and **append to the value** of below input tags

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="new_title" value="">//title should come here
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="new_price" value="">//price should come here
<select class="form-control" name="new_price_update">//if price_update==1 then Yes should be select, else No will be select
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="0">No</option>
</select>
```

> Note : I check all stack Question but unable to find better solution for this

Comment: At your success function you can get id by `data.id`,title= `data.title`. I think you can set values of this input fields now.

Comment: You already got answers.

Comment: Some have already answer your question, but on a side note you should absolutely change you Controller code to prevent SQL injections (if it's the actual code you provided here, of course). An attacker could really easily do whatever they want with your database. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
success: function(data) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(obj[0]['title']);
    console.log(obj[0]['price']);
    //etc..
}
```

I hope this will work..

Answer (score 1):

use `$.parseJSON`
you are getting `data` in ajax success. so first step is to parse it using `parseJSON` 
then after input tags add some divs with separate identifiers.
then append it like follow.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $( "#update_prod" ).click(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var head= $("#update_product").val();
            $.ajax(
                {
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type:"post",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/update_product",
                    data:{ product:head},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                     var result= jQuery.parseJSON ( data );
                     $('#title').html(result.title);
                     $('#price').html(result.price);
                     //check condition for select box
                     if(result.price_update==1)
                     $('select').val('Yes');
                     else
                     $('#select').val('No');

                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

your html now

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="new_title" value="">
<div id='title'></div>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="new_price" value="">
 <div id='price'></div>
    <select class="form-control" id='select' name="new_price_update"> 
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
```

Hope it will work for you , Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

replace update_product() last line  `echo json_encode($result);` by

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($result));
```

Add this line in success function of ajax

```
 $.each(data, function (a, b){
         $('input[name="new_title"]').val(b.title);
         $('input[name="new_price"]').val(b.price);
  $('select[name="new_price_update"]').val(b.price_update);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ajax` `success` method, retrieve the results using `JSON.parse` like this:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data) {

        //This line turns the JSON string echoed from your PHP into a JS object
        var json_obj = JSON.parse(data);

        //since your PHP created an array, we iterate through the object
        $.each(json_obj, function(index, result){
            console.log(result.title);
            console.log(result.price);
            console.log(result.id);
            //etc..
        });
    }
    ...
});
```

The above should output your desired results to your browser's console. All you need to do now is parse this information to whatever element you want to place it in. So if you have an input with ID of `"my_input_price"`, you will do `$("#my_input_price").val(result.price);` and so on.